# MacOS Low Storage Warning

Tags: macos

Any idea why the low storage message is appearing?

[image]

Update 2022-06-17:

Here's some more information.

[image]

Also this...

[image]

Comment: Which incarnation of Mac OS?

Comment: High Sierra, 10.13.6.

Comment: Maybe it can't expand the disk. How much space is left on the actual drive this sits on & what format is it? Also, post results of `diskutil list` or `diskutil cs list` [one will give info, the other not] & get a picture of the overview of Disk Utility.